# How do I parse a response from Apple Terminal or an Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm working on a project with my video production equipment at my church which I think, if seen to completion and successful, could be of significant help to those using similar equipment whether in low level broadcast, studio, or houses of worship.

Here is my situation. I have 2 robotic PTZ cameras that are controlled via CGI over IP commands from a software (Rocosoft PTZ Joy Sutd that support preset positions.  Depending on where people are standing on stage, I can have their positions saved and recalled easily. I have an Blackmagic Design ATEM video switcher which takes those two camera inputs and be set to our program output.

Here is the problem: One can accidentally click a different position preset while live on the ATEM program output which is BAD. This results in roller coaster like movement as the PTZ jumps from one position to the next.

Here is what I think the solution is: I need to monitor the ATEM switcher status and create an applescript or something to first check the status of the ATEM switcher, see if the PTZ cam is live on program output, and BLOCK the software's commands for presets if that camera is live.

I can receive that status of the ATEM using a command line tool in terminal called OSCchief (open sound control protocol) which will listen to the ATEM and give me the status of all program / preview values. This software will also send OSC commands too.

Not sure if this is helpful but, this OSCchief command line tool i think had to be based off the Blackmagic ATEM's original protocol, UDP, which has been reverse engineered by Skaarhoj and its documented on their github page.

https://www.skaarhoj.com/fileadmin/BMDPROTOCOL.html

Its UDP packets which ive confirmed with wireshark.

So How can I make a script which takes the input of OSCchief (or the original UDP protocol if that'd be better) and parse that text or look for the specific character. Here is what OSCchief looks like

Last login: Wed Feb 20 09:16:51 on ttys000
Video-Booth-Mac-Pro:~ macpro2$ oscchief listen 4444
Start listening on port '4444' for incoming OSC messages...

```
/atem/program/0 f 0.000000
/atem/program/1 f 0.000000
/atem/program/2 f 0.000000
/atem/program/3 f 0.000000
/atem/program/4 f 1.000000
/atem/program/5 f 0.000000
/atem/program/6 f 0.000000
/atem/program/7 f 0.000000
/atem/program/8 f 0.000000
/atem/program/9 f 0.000000
/atem/program/10 f 0.000000
/atem/program/11 f 0.000000
/atem/program/12 f 0.000000
```

the number after the letter f is what changes. 1.00... means output active, 0 inactive.

I apologize if any of this confusing.. because well, some of it is confusing to me. I'm willing to do more research! I don't expect to be spoon fed. Would greatly appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

thanks!

-Zack

Comment: Ok, let's assume we can write a script that starts `oscchief` and reads the stream and can know at any given time whether recording is active - that's easy. What's the next bit? It has to block something if the recording is active - what does it have to block specifically and how can it block it?

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for the reply. So, the script would then have to block the CGI IP commands coming from my preset software, Rocosoft PTZ Joy Studio. The typical setup is, the software talks directly to the IP address of the camera. My thought was, I enter the IP address of the computer with the script and the software sends the command to the computer rather than to the camera. Then the script forwards the command on to the camera after it checks the switcher status first.

Comment: Oh, that sounds like a switchable relay. It relays incoming commands to a camera unless a recording is happening. Mmmmm... it is now getting more complicated. How often do commands come in - is it at a high data rate? How many different commands are there that would need relaying? Do we know the format of all the commands?

Comment: The commands only come in as often as we issue them which is about 1 every 7 seconds. The command format is CGI (common gateway interface)  Like this http://192.168.0.10/cgi-bin/aw_ptz?cmd=#PTS5050&res=1 . The original protocol of the ATEM switcher is UDP but people have taken that and written thinks like oscchief to turn it into OSC commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple idea for communicating between two processes just using the filesystem. Other methods are available, but this is simple...

Continuously monitor the output from `oscchief` and create a file called `/tmp/RECORDING` if recording is in progress, and delete that file if it is not. Then, other processes, such as your CGI, can then simply check whether the file is present or not to know if recording is active, and whether it should suppress commands.

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# monitor
# Mark Setchell
#
# Continuously monitor the output of the "oscchief" program to determine if a
# recording is in progress. If it is, create a sentinel file in /tmp that other
# processes (e.g. CGIs) can check in order to find recording status. Delete the
# file if recording is not taking place, or when exiting so that programs will
# not be prevented from running.
################################################################################

SentinelFile="/tmp/RECORDING"

# Add the directory containing "oscchief" below
PATH="$PATH":/path/to/directory/containing/oscchief

# Called when program is terminated
cleanup(){
    echo "Cleaning up..."
    rm "$SentinelFile" 2> /dev/null
}

trap 'cleanup' SIGINT SIGABRT SIGQUIT SIGTERM

# Continuously tail the output of "oscchief"
oscchief | while read -r line ; do
    # If line contains "1.00" recording is active
    if [[ $line == *"1.00"* ]]; then
        touch "$SentinelFile"
    else
        rm "$SentinelFile" 2> /dev/null
    fi
done
```

To test this out, save the above script in your HOME directory as `monitor` and make it executable by starting Terminal and running:

```
chmod +x monitor
```

You can then run it with:

```
./monitor
```

You can then watch `/tmp` by starting **Finder** and pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and typing `/tmp` into the box that pops up.

In the normal use case, under macOS, you would launch this script via `launchctl` so that it always runs - there are lots of tutorials and examples of that on StackOverflow.

You then change the CGI program called `cgi-bin/aw_ptz` (whose source I cannot see) so that it alters its behaviour depending on the presence or absence of the sentinel file.

---

Other possibilities that spring to mind for addressing some aspects of your question:

- put a wrapper around your CGI script to intercept calls,
- symlink your CGI script to the original or a dummy version, depending on whether a recording is running,
- create an `ssh` tunnel to your CGI script that you stop during recording,
- storing the recording status in Redis rather than in the filesystem.